# Is it possible to use view binding in a static method?

Tags: android, static, android-viewbinding

My question is, if it is possible to use view binding in a static method:

```
class SomeFragment : FragmentBinding<SomeFragmentBinding>() {

 companion object {
   fun someRandomFunction() {
    // Use view binding here
    binding.textView.text = "Test"
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binding` is a non-static property of `SomeFragment` class, where as `companion object` are static. Static methods cannot access non-static properties, because each instance of the class would have their own instances of that non-static property.

So, you cannot access `binding` or any other non-static property inside `companion object`.